# Finding a value in an array of class objects

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, object

Is there a way to find a value of in an array of class objects. Then once it is found to be included, can you find what place within the array it resides at? E.g.

```
class SomeClass
def initialize(value,otherData)
      @value = value
      @otherData = otherData
 end
end

x = 0
otherData = "foo"
list = Array.new
while (x < 3)
     list.push SomeClass.new(x,otherData)
     x += 1
end
```

I want to find list[x].value where value=2 and figure out what place in the array that is located at.

Comment: Your code is invalid. What is `value` method? Your camel case local variables give really bad impression.

Comment: I think you just have to iterate over the array of objects, look at the value within the object, and go from there

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index

Comment: Code isn't invalid and it was just sample, wasn't looking to argue camelCase versus underscore_case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SomeClass had a `value` method, an obvious way would be:

```
ix = list.find_index { |sc| sc.value == 2 }
```